# Discuss the limit of a sequence as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question requires the evaluation of the expression 
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a^n+1}$$ 
as $n$ approaches infinity.

My approach was expressing the fraction as $-1/(1+a^n ) + a^n/(1+a^n)$ and evaluating the limit I am getting $1$.

Am I in the right track or someone to guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you *actually* mean some series, or the limit of **the sequence** ? Is it given what $\;a\;$ is?

Comment: This is a sequence because it is given as an expression and not as sum of the expression

Comment: if it is not given what $a$ is we must do case work

Comment: @Pethias Good...and then why **did you** write "series" in the question's title?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I initially thought it was a series because the question was given to me under series but I later realized that a series must be well defined.

Answer (score 2):

If $|a|>1$ then $1/a^n\to 0$ and,
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a^n+1}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{a^n}}{1+\frac{1}{a^n}}\to 1.$$

If $a=1$ then
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a^n+1}=0\to 0.$$

If $a=-1$ then the fraction is not defined  for $n$ odd.

If $|a|<1$ then $a^n\to 0$ and 
$$\frac{a^n-1}{a^n+1}\to -1$$

Answer (score 0):

if $a>1$ ist hold we can write $$\frac{a^n(1-\frac{1}{a^n})}{a^n(1+\frac{1}{a^n})}$$ and we get $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{a^n}=0$$ and our searched limit is $1$
can you proceed with the other cases?